# двумерный вектор удаление элементов по условию

Tags: c++

```
f   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if (ball.CheckCollision(blocks[i][j].getRect()))
        {
            ball.ReflectHorizontal();
            ++ccount;

            auto it = blocks[i].begin() + j;
            it = blocks[i].erase(it);
            //blocks[i][j].crush();
            if (ccount == 5)
            {
                ball.SetSpeedX();
                ball.SetSpeedY();


            }
            if (ccount == 15)
            {
                Restartwin();
            }

        }
    }
}
//Делаю арканоид и хочу что бы когда мячик касается кирпича(которые по сути вектор векторов кирпичей), что бы определенный кирпич удалялся.
```

Comment: С помощью erase, возвращающей иттератор. Циклы сделайте по итераторам, и напишите j=Ball.erase(j)

Comment: а можешь показать? сори, я слегка новичок в этом

Comment: Все легче - попробуйте там где нужно удалять, вставить `std::vector<Тип вектора ball>::iterator it = ball[i] begin() + j; it = ball[i] .erase(it);`

Comment: почему то выходит ошибка, т.е шарик касается ошибка кирпича и ловит ошибку out of range

Comment: Вектор ball состоит из вектора так? Нужно указать в 'Типе вектора' не тип вектора ball, а тип вектора который является типом вектора ball

Comment: ball это мячик который касается блоков  if (ball.CheckCollision(blocks[i][j].getRect()) происходит проверка касания, я сделал вектор векторов блоков, и пытаюсь в  векторе векторов удалить элемент, но постоянно выскакивает ошибка, что выхожу за пределы.

Answer (score 1):

```
    typedef std::vector<block> b; // вектор блоков
    std::vector<b> blocks; // вектор векторов блоков
    for (std::vector<b>::iterator it = blocks.begin(); it != blocks.end(); ++it)
    {
        for (std::vector<block>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
        {
            //....
            if (ball.CheckCollision(it2->getRect())) it2 = (it)->erase(it2);
        }
    }
```

Typedef'ом назвал вектор блоков `b`. Класс блока - `block`, сам же двумерный вектор - `blocks`.
Вот сам цикл с итераторами.

Answer (score 0):

Если элемент удалён из вектора, то его длина ведь сократится, так?
А цикл for об этом не знает и колбасит до указанного в начале индекса.
А элемента с таким индексом уже нет...
А идущий после удалённого встал на его место и не был вообще проверен...

Используйте цикл в обратном направлении (лучше обратный итератор - он ведь всё равно нужен для erase)

(или проверяйте окончание цикла по длине вектора - но в этом случае придётся ещё обрабатывать элемент после удалённого)